# Geoserver - generating tiles - bbox is incorrect

Tags: geoserver, tiles

I am beginner in geoserver. I would like to generate tiles in geoserver. I have added the layer to geoserver. When i choose the option to 'Preview layer' i can see the layer with the correct bbox:
[image]

Then, i go to gwc, i choose the option 'seed this layer', and feel in this part as follows:
Number of tasks to use: 01
Type of operation:  Seed - Generate missing tiles 
Grid Set:   EPSG:4326
Format: image / png
Zoom start: 00
Zoom stop:  02
Bounding box:   -4.601615515076983 39.8769407866263 -3.0527184873294764 41.16710732525929

And as a result i can see almost all of the tiles completely white and one tile with black point...
[image]

Why does it happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zoom level 0 in the Geoserver/GeoWebCache gridset EPSG:4326 contains two tiles and splits the world into two halves. Zoom level 1 has 3x2 tiles and level 2 6x4 tiles. Seeding process probably creates one tile for you at all these levels (the tile that encloses your data) but because of the scale you don even see it until Z2 and still it is just a dot.  Continue the seeding till higher levels and you will be able to zoom in and see the details from your data.

Comment: Thanks for your replay @user30184. But is there any way that at zoom 0 I can see all my zone and avoid all that white space around? I thought that by choosing BBOX the zoom level 0 will display only the zone that i have chosen in BBOX.

Comment: One tile at zoom level 0 covers half of the world. Gridset EPSG:4326 is fixed and you can't change it. Start seeding at more suitable level, let's say 6 or something. If you really wish you can also make your own tailored gridset where level 0 covers your data nicely but I do not believe that you want to do that. Remember also that EPSG:4326 is really using geographic projection. You may rather want to use the EPSG:900913 gridset for making your maps to look the same as in OSM and Google maps.